# Notation $(S^nF)(-L)$ in algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, notation

Let $X$ be an algebraic surface and $F$ a vector bundle on $X$, and $S^nF$ the $n$-th symmetric power of $F$, and $L$ a line bundle on $X$. What does the notation $S^nF(-L)$ mean? Is it $(S^nF)\otimes L^{-1}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for a coherent sheaf $\mathcal F$ on $X$, $\mathcal F(-L)$ always denotes $\mathcal F \otimes_{\mathcal O_X} L^{-1}$.